# Restricting API Key Access with long TLD broken in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places

I have a site with a long TLD: ".immobilien" API restricton based on URL doesn't work at all.

I have a working szenario with a different setup. The key is restricted to:

`*.SOMESITE.com/*`

without protocol.

I now set it up the same way:

`*.SOMESITE.immobilien/*`

and it doesn't work. Browser Console still shows me

> Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
>   Your site URL to be authorized: https://SOMESITE.immobilien/

Fair enough - it works being set to an individual absolut link. But I need to get wildcards working. Is there a way to debug what referrer gets send and if it should pass the syntax of the restriction?

(What I did to make sure its not a simple fault: cleared cache, tried different browsers, exchanged Google API keys...)

Comment: `*.SOMESITE.immobilien/*` doesn't match `https://SOMESITE.immobilien/`

Comment: why? shouldn't * be anything or nothing?

Comment: it is `*.` that causes the issue.  That makes it match any subdomain of the specified domain, but not match the domain itself.  Does your "working domain" include a `www.` (or some other subdomaim)?  An additional rule for `SOMESITE.immobilien/*` might work.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to apply something like the following as restrictions to your API key:

```
http://example.immobilien/*
https://example.immobilien/*
http://*.example.immobilien/*
https://*.example.immobilien/*
```

This will allow Maps JavaScript API calls from http:// and https:// domains, calls from other pages of your domains and subdomains.

If you are still having problems with this, it would be best if you seek help from [Google Maps Platform technical support](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support).

Hope this helps!